# parse XML with all its attributes - Laravel orchestra Parser

Tags: xml, laravel, orchestra

I want to parse all XML attributes.

I wasn't able to access **(NAME & TYPE)** from :

```
 <productlist name="MRF">

 <product type="BAT">
```

Can someone help me parse these attributes with the rest of the data?

```
$xml = XmlParser::load(url(myxmlfile.xml));

$xmlProduct = $xml->parse([

   'product'   => [
      'uses'=>'product[name,price,type]'
   ],

]);
```

My XML Example

```
<productlist name="MRF">
     <product type="BAT">
        <name>
           <![CDATA[ mrf genius limited edition ]]>
        </name>
        <price>
           <![CDATA[ 11999 ]]>
        </price>
        <type>
           <![CDATA[ english willow ]]>
        </type>
     </product>
 </productlist>
```

Comment: I've never used Orchestra for Laravel before, so that's why I won't post this as an answer, but I made a Laravel package to make handling xml conversion a breeze. You can find it here: https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array

You could easily do: ``$data = xml_to_array(file_get_contents(url('myxmlfile.xml')))``

Comment: @Mark this Laravel orchestra Parser is working fine but what I'm looking for is...How to access (NAME & TYPE) from :
       <productlist name="MRF">

        <product type="BAT">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the links to the documentation

https://packagist.org/packages/orchestra/parser

https://github.com/orchestral/parser

This is what I did to solve my problem :

```
use Orchestra\Parser\Xml\Facade as XmlParser;

$xml = XmlParser::load(url(myxmlfile.xml));
$xmlProduct = $xml->parse([ 

     'name' => ['uses' => '::name'],
     'Type' => ['uses' => 'product::type'],
     'price' => ['uses' => 'product.price'],
     'bat_type' => ['uses' => 'product.type'],
);
```

This is how I was able to parse my xml.

Comment: What is that. How can you get nested parameter without path definition? I have a problem to understand how it works. There is no documentation....

Comment: @Čamo check now I've edited this answer or you can tell more about your issue so that I can help you more clearly.

Comment: Meanwhile I found it. Thanks.